# Docker on Windows: Unable to create: Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled

Tags: docker-for-windows

Any clue?  Can't seem to run Docker on Windows 10 to save my life :(
Installed and reinstalled this thing multiple times, disabled/enabled HyperV, nothing.  Does the log file indicate anything to anyone?

```
Version: 17.03.1-ce-win5 (10743)
Channel: stable
Sha1: b18e2a50ccf296bcd637b330c0ca9faaab9d790c
Started on: 2017/05/09 15:23:22.316
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Edition: Professional
Id: 1607
Build: 14393
BuildLabName: 14393.953.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.170303-1614
File: C:\Users\akamen\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe" 
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[15:23:22.505][GUI            ][Info   ] Starting...
[15:23:22.912][Tracking       ][Info   ] Crash report and usage statistics are enabled
[15:23:22.925][SegmentApi     ][Info   ] Usage statistic: appLaunched
[15:23:23.198][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...
[15:23:23.239][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version
[15:23:23.242][SegmentApi     ][Info   ] Usage statistic: heartbeat
[15:23:15.514][BackendServer  ][Info   ] Started
[15:23:23.235][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()
[15:23:23.235][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.0005001.
[15:23:23.739][Updater        ][Info   ] Checking for updates on channel stable...
[15:23:23.740][Notifications  ][Info   ] Docker is starting...
[15:23:23.754][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Start(Docker.Core.Settings)...
[15:23:23.757][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Start(Docker.Core.Settings)
[15:23:23.762][PowerMode      ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:23.765][HyperV         ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:23.774][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Stop True...
[15:23:23.777][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Creating a Runspace Pool...
[15:23:23.845][Updater        ][Info   ] Local build 10743 is as good as the remote 10743 on channel stable
[15:23:23.931][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Runspace Pool created (Min=1, Max=2)
[15:23:23.994][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:23.988
[15:23:25.562][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:25.561
[15:23:25.773][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM does not exist
[15:23:25.774][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [stop] took 00:00:02.0072553 to run
[15:23:25.774][OptimizeDisk   ][Info   ] Optimize
[15:23:25.775][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...
[15:23:25.791][Moby           ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:25.816][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] Installing GUIDs...
[15:23:25.816][PowerMode      ][Info   ] Start
[15:23:25.817][HyperV         ][Info   ] Create
[15:23:25.817][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Create True -VhdPathOverride  -SwitchSubnetAddress 10.0.75.0 -SwitchSubnetMaskSize 24 -CPUs 2 -Memory 2048 -IsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\mobylinux.iso...
[15:23:25.818][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] GUIDs installed
[15:23:25.821][Firewall       ][Info   ] Removing all existing rules...
[15:23:25.826][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:25.826
[15:23:25.890][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:25.890
[15:23:25.908][Firewall       ][Info   ] All existing rules are removed.
[15:23:25.908][Firewall       ][Info   ] Opening ports for C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\com.docker.proxy.exe...
[15:23:25.919][Firewall       ][Info   ] Opening ports for SMB...
[15:23:25.963][Firewall       ][Info   ] Ports are opened
[15:23:26.112][HyperV         ][Info   ] Creating Switch: DockerNAT...
[15:23:27.678][HyperV         ][Info   ] Switch created.
[15:23:28.481][Linux          ][Error  ] Failed to start: Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled

. Let's retry
[15:23:28.484][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...
[15:23:30.094][HyperV         ][Info   ] Hyper-V is running
[15:23:30.095][PowerMode      ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:30.095][HyperV         ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:30.095][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Stop True...
[15:23:30.118][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:30.117
[15:23:30.136][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:30.136
[15:23:30.152][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM does not exist
[15:23:30.152][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [stop] took 00:00:00.0570078 to run
[15:23:30.152][OptimizeDisk   ][Info   ] Optimize
[15:23:30.152][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...
[15:23:30.168][Moby           ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:30.200][HyperV         ][Info   ] Destroy
[15:23:30.201][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Destroy True -KeepVolume True...
[15:23:30.209][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:30.209
[15:23:30.229][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:30.224
[15:23:30.242][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM does not exist
[15:23:30.244][HyperV         ][Info   ] Destroying Switch DockerNAT...
[15:23:30.829][HyperV         ][Info   ] Removing VM MobyLinuxVM...
[15:23:30.844][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [destroy] took 00:00:00.6434914 to run
[15:23:30.844][Firewall       ][Info   ] Closing ports...
[15:23:30.844][Firewall       ][Info   ] Removing all existing rules...
[15:23:30.958][Firewall       ][Info   ] All existing rules are removed.
[15:23:30.958][Firewall       ][Info   ] Ports are closed
[15:23:30.958][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] Removing GUIDs...
[15:23:30.960][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] GUIDs removed
[15:23:30.960][HyperV         ][Info   ] Create
[15:23:30.961][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Create True -VhdPathOverride  -SwitchSubnetAddress 10.0.75.0 -SwitchSubnetMaskSize 24 -CPUs 2 -Memory 2048 -IsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\mobylinux.iso...
[15:23:30.968][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:30.968
[15:23:30.983][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:30.983
[15:23:31.074][HyperV         ][Info   ] Creating Switch: DockerNAT...
[15:23:32.184][HyperV         ][Info   ] Switch created.
[15:23:32.325][PowerMode      ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:32.325][HyperV         ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:32.325][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Stop True...
[15:23:32.333][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:32.333
[15:23:32.346][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:32.346
[15:23:32.358][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM does not exist
[15:23:32.358][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [stop] took 00:00:00.0325014 to run
[15:23:32.358][OptimizeDisk   ][Info   ] Optimize
[15:23:32.358][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...
[15:23:32.369][Moby           ][Info   ] Stop
[15:23:32.386][HyperV         ][Info   ] Destroy
[15:23:32.386][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Destroy True -KeepVolume True...
[15:23:32.393][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 15:23:32.393
[15:23:32.406][HyperV         ][Info   ] Module loaded at 15:23:32.406
[15:23:32.418][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM does not exist
[15:23:32.419][HyperV         ][Info   ] Destroying Switch DockerNAT...
[15:23:32.999][HyperV         ][Info   ] Removing VM MobyLinuxVM...
[15:23:33.010][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [destroy] took 00:00:00.6234920 to run
[15:23:33.010][Firewall       ][Info   ] Closing ports...
[15:23:33.010][Firewall       ][Info   ] Removing all existing rules...
[15:23:33.047][Firewall       ][Info   ] All existing rules are removed.
[15:23:33.047][Firewall       ][Info   ] Ports are closed
[15:23:33.047][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] Removing GUIDs...
[15:23:33.048][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] GUIDs removed
[15:23:33.050][NamedPipeServer][Error  ] Unable to execute Start: Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled

    at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
[15:23:33.148][NamedPipeClient][Error  ] Unable to send Start: Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled


[15:23:33.150][Notifications  ][Error  ] Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled


[15:27:28.054][ErrorReportWindow][Info   ] Open logs
```